# iOS UITableView swipe haptic feedback

Tags: ios, uikit, haptic-feedback

Since iOS 11 (actually I think I noticed that in iOS 10 as well) there is a slightly noticeable "click" when swiping table view cells in the beginning (in Mail.app for example). I've noticed the same "click" on launching applications from Home Screen in iOS 11. It sounds like haptic engine is warming up just before performing the feedback.

Some users consider it to be [a bug](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80669), however I believe it's something that was made on purpose.

So I was trying to reproduce this feedback with `UIFeedbackGenerator`s without any luck, any ideas how can it be implemented and is there a way to achieve that effect using public API?